# mssql calculate total by hour

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains basically an error log.  These errors arrive based on various factors and have various severities.  I am trying to get a query put together the total of each severity per hour in a 24 hour period.

I have it working, except for one small item.  The results are sorted by the Hour, which always starts at 0.  What I need is for it to be in true time sequence.  Meaning that if the query is run at noon on 6/23, the query needs to have the first record at noon 6/22.

Sample table data:
    ID                  created         severity

```
FL41988194-51133    4/13/2014 20:21 critical
JO03982444-74849    4/14/2014 12:46 major
JO03982444-74852    4/14/2014 12:46 major
JO03982444-74855    4/14/2014 12:46 major
BY79194841-06182    4/19/2014 19:54 major
BY79194841-06183    4/19/2014 19:54 major
BY79194841-06184    4/19/2014 19:54 major
TV90425333-88384    5/20/2014 7:02  major
FZ23706935-25024    6/7/2014 14:56  major
SY05532197-47119    6/12/2014 3:57  major
```

Here is my current code:

```
    select 

    [Hour], ISNULL([Critical],0) as Critical, ISNULL([Major],0) as Major, ISNULL([Minor],0) as Minor, ISNULL([Warning],0) as Warning,  
    ISNULL([Information],0) as Information, 
    ISNULL([Critical],0) + ISNULL([Warning],0) + ISNULL([Major],0) + ISNULL([Minor],0) + ISNULL([Information],0) as [Total]

    from
    (SELECT 
        DATEPART(hh, created) as 'Hour',
        [severity],
          count([id]) as incidents
      FROM [ALARM_TRANSACTION_SUMMARY]
      where created >= GETDATE()-1 
      group by DATEPART(hh, created), severity
    **Union ALL
   select NumberValue, NULL, NULL
   From NumberTable**
      ) PS
    PIVOT
    (
    SUM (incidents)
    FOR severity IN
    ( [Critical], [Information], Major, Minor, Warning)
    ) AS pvt
```

The Current output would look like this:

```
Hour      Critical     Major     Minor     Warning    Information     Total 

----      --------     -----     -----     -------    -----------     -----
 0            0          0         0         0            0             0
 1            0          0         0         0            0             0
 2            0          0         0         0            0             0
 3            0          1         0         0            0             1
 4            0          0         0         0            0             0
 5            0          0         0         0            0             0
 6            0          0         0         0            0             0
 7            0          1         0         0            0             1
 8            0          0         0         0            0             0
 9            0          0         0         0            0             0
 10           0          0         0         0            0             0
 11           0          0         0         0            0             0
 12           0          3         0         0            0             3
 13           0          0         0         0            0             0
 14           0          1         0         0            0             1
 15           0          0         0         0            0             0
 16           0          0         0         0            0             0
 17           0          0         0         0            0             0
 18           0          0         0         0            0             0
 19           0          2         0         0            0             2
 20           1          0         0         0            0             1
 21           0          0         0         0            0             0
 22           0          0         0         0            0             0
 23           0          0         0         0            0             0
```

As I said above, this does give me the hourly totals, but the totals are in the wrong sort order...so if I ran this at 2pm, I need the output to look like this:

```
Hour      Critical     Major     Minor     Warning    Information     Total 

----      --------     -----     -----     -------    -----------     -----
 14           0          1         0         0            0             1
 15           0          0         0         0            0             0
 16           0          0         0         0            0             0
 17           0          0         0         0            0             0
 18           0          0         0         0            0             0
 19           0          2         0         0            0             2
 20           1          0         0         0            0             1
 21           0          0         0         0            0             0
 22           0          0         0         0            0             0
 23           0          0         0         0            0             0
 0            0          0         0         0            0             0
 1            0          0         0         0            0             0
 2            0          0         0         0            0             0
 3            0          1         0         0            0             1
 4            0          0         0         0            0             0
 5            0          0         0         0            0             0
 6            0          0         0         0            0             0
 7            0          1         0         0            0             1
 8            0          0         0         0            0             0
 9            0          0         0         0            0             0
 10           0          0         0         0            0             0
 11           0          0         0         0            0             0
 12           0          3         0         0            0             3
 13           0          0         0         0            0             0
```

One other thing.  This is feeding a report that requires the data to be presented as above (the charting software isn't smart enough to use the raw data and subtotal by the timestamps).

Comment: after looking at this for just a minute, I would think you need to change `group by DATEPART(hh, created), severity` to something that uses the date and hour.  You might have to include the date in the `hour` column and then later strip it out for display (use a derived table or CTE)

Comment: Grab the max or min timestamp per hour and sort on it. that way day comes into play and the sort works.  shouldn't have to display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query.

```
select 

[Hour], ISNULL([Critical],0) as Critical, ISNULL([Major],0) as Major, ISNULL([Minor],0) as Minor, ISNULL([Warning],0) as Warning,  
ISNULL([Information],0) as Information, 
ISNULL([Critical],0) + ISNULL([Warning],0) + ISNULL([Major],0) + ISNULL([Minor],0) + ISNULL([Information],0) as [Total]

from
(SELECT 
    DATEPART(hh, created) as 'Hour',
    DATEPART(hh, DATEADD(hh,-DATEPART(hh, created),GetDate())) AS SortHour,
    [severity],
      count([id]) as incidents
  FROM [ALARM_TRANSACTION_SUMMARY]
  where created >= GETDATE()-1 
  group by DATEPART(hh, created), severity
  Union ALL
   select NumberValue,DATEPART(hh, DATEADD(hh,-NumberValue,GetDate())), NULL, NULL
   From NumberTable
  ) PS
PIVOT
(
SUM (incidents)
FOR severity IN
( [Critical], [Information], Major, Minor, Warning)
) AS pvt
order by SortHour
```

Comment: Hi Kiran,  Forgot one item (updated the post above).  I am performing a "union all" to a number table to force the "zero" count hours.  With the current solution, this doesn't work...unless i've missed something very simple...which is very possible.  Is there a way to get the two to merge again?  I need to show "zero" values for the hours with no record counts.

Comment: I am not sure what the NumberTable contains, just updated the query, can you check if this works?

Comment: Sorry...the number table is simply a single column table with numbers going from 0 to 23

Comment: What the output does is combines 1 through 23 to start and then shows the sorted columns with values...

Comment: That was the trick...thank you very much for the help...that would have had me drinking by 2pm if I was on my own ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
(original query)
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN [Hour] >= DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE())
        THEN [Hour]
        ELSE [Hour] + 24
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

UNTESTED but from appearances this should work;  don't think we need to include it in the select.

```
SELECT   
 [Hour], ISNULL([Critical],0) as Critical, ISNULL([Major],0) as Major, ISNULL([Minor],0) as Minor, ISNULL([Warning],0) as Warning,  
 ISNULL([Information],0) as Information, 
 ISNULL([Critical],0) + ISNULL([Warning],0) + ISNULL([Major],0) + ISNULL([Minor],0) + ISNULL([Information],0) as [Total]
FROM
    (SELECT 
        DATEPART(hh, created) as 'Hour',
        [severity],
          count([id]) as incidents,
        max(created) as SortDate
      FROM [ALARM_TRANSACTION_SUMMARY]
      where created >= GETDATE()-1 
      group by DATEPART(hh, created), severity, max(created)
      ) PS
    PIVOT
    (
    SUM (incidents)
    FOR severity IN
    ( [Critical], [Information], Major, Minor, Warning)
    ) AS pvt
    ORDER BY sortDate desc;
```